# SQL fill in a table with data

Tags: sql, matrix-multiplication

I am doing a matrix multiplication project which involves with matrix 
So here is my table format:

```
   create table A ( row integer, col integer, val integer);
```

What i need to do is to fill in each table with data,
Task 1: create a 200*200 matrix A and all of its element initialized to 1. 
        That means I would do manually 
insert<0,0,1> <0,1,1> <0,2,1> ....<0,199,1> 
insert<1,0,1> <1,1,1> <0,2,1> .....<1,199,1> and so

Task 2: create 200*200 matrix A and its diagonal elements are 1's.

So I am wondering instead of doing this manually, if there anyway to automate initialize all the elements? 
The following is an attempt using while loop:

```
create table A ( row integer, col integer, val integer);
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0
DECLARE @count2 INT
SET @count2 = 0
WHILE (@count < 200)
BEGIN
   WHILE (@count2 <200)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO A([row], [col]) VALUES (@count, @counts)
      SET @count2 = (@count2 + 1)
   END
   SET @count = (@count + 1)
END
```

This the above correct? I am fairly new to sql:(

Comment: Thanks, I just included an attempt using while. I was not aware of the possibility of while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid loops and iterative stuff.  You're in SQL Server - think set-based

Try this

```
insert into A( row, col, val )
select row, col, 1
from 
(
        SELECT Row = number from master..spt_values 
        where type='P' and number between 1 and 200
) Rows
CROSS JOIN
(
        SELECT Col = number from master..spt_values 
        where type='P' and number between 1 and 200
) Cols
```

For your second requirement, you can be lazy and add

```
where Row = Col
```

If it's a one-off thing then this ought to be ok.

The `master..spt_values` bit is all about getting a range of numbers between 1 and 200. You can also have this variation:

```
; WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT n = number  FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE type = 'P'  AND  number BETWEEN 1 AND 20
  ) 
INSERT INTO A ( row, col, val )
SELECT Rows.n, Cols.n, 1
FROM
    cte AS Rows
  CROSS JOIN
    cte AS Cols ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit - the CTE is cleaner assuming the rows and columns remain the same.  Given that the asker was starting with cursors I dind't want to frighten with a CTE :)